# Access second row of MySQL query result in Go

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I am running a MySQL query in Go. I want access the second row of the query result. I know I can use

```
for rows.Next {

}
```

But I don't want to run a loop for accessing the second row (and then breaking the loop after it iterates the second time).
What to do?

Here is a code snippet:

```
rows,err:= db.Query("SELECT status,ts FROM events WHERE node = ? order by ts desc limit 2", testNode.ID);
defer rows.Close()
if ( err!= nil){
    t.Error("Some Error" + err.Error())
}
isNext:=rows.Next()
if(isNext == false) {
    t.Error(" No rows in query result")
}
rows.Scan(&status)
// What to do to use second row ?
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Sticking to [`DB.Query()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query)

If you're going to discard the first row, there is no point in retrieving it from the database.

Use `LIMIT 1, 1` to discard the first result and limit the result to 1 row (check out the doc of `LIMIT` at: [MySQL SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)). Then simply proceed reading the first row which will be the 2nd row of your query result:

```
q := "SELECT status, ts FROM events WHERE node = ? order by ts desc limit 1, 1"
rows, err := db.Query(query, testNode.ID);
if err != nil {
    t.Error("Error:", err)
    return
}
defer rows.Close()

if !rows.Next() {
    t.Error("No result")
    return
}
if err := rows.Scan(&status); err != nil {
    t.Error("Failed to scan:", err)
    return
}

// All good, use status
fmt.Println("Status:", status)
```

More examples using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

#### Using to [`DB.QueryRow()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow)

If you're expecting at most 1 row, you may also use `DB.QueryRow()` and the result will be much more compact:

```
q := "SELECT status, ts FROM events WHERE node = ? order by ts desc limit 1, 1"
if err := db.QueryRow(query, testNode.ID).Scan(&status); err != nil {
    t.Error("Failed to scan, no result?")
    return
}

// All good, use status
fmt.Println("Status:", status)
```

Comment: Actually I want to compare an attribute of top 2 rows. So I am not discarding first row . So your answer doesn't solve my problem I guess.

Comment: @user3150716 If you want to compare the first 2 rows, then you don't want to read the 2nd row but the first 2 rows. Your question is misleading.